# Aplicación streaming audio

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de practica en Android Estudio que es una radio o streaming de audio ,necesitaría su ayuda por que no logro hacer que funcione.En teoría,como esta ahora,únicamente reproduce el audio,todavía no coloque funcionalidades a los botones sobrantes.

java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 ImageButton btnPlay;
 ImageButton btnRec;
 ImageButton btnStp;
 Button btnMul;
 Button btnRa;
 Button btnNos;

 MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
 String stream="http://streams.calmradio.com/api/29/128/stream/;";
 boolean prepared,started=false;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         btnPlay=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
         btnRec=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.reconectar);
         btnStp=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.parar);
         btnMul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.multimedia);
         btnRa=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio);
         btnNos=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nosotros);

         Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Esperando respúesta del Servidor...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         toast.show();
         btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
         btnRec.setEnabled(false);
         btnStp.setEnabled(false);

         mediaplayer=new MediaPlayer();
         mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

         new PlayerTask().execute(stream);


     }
          class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{

             @Override
             protected Boolean doinBackground(String...String){
                 try{
                     mediaplayer.setDataSource(String[0]);
                     mediaplayer.prepare();
                     prepared=true;
                 }catch(IOException e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 return prepared;
             }

             @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean){

              super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
              mediaplayer.start();

             }

          }
 }
```

y este el xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/fondo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/radio"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/nosotros"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nosotros"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/nosotros"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/multimedia"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/multimedia"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/nosotros"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/base"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/reconectar"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_rotate"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/play"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/parar"
    android:layout_width="82dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/play"
    />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Según el compilador tengo un error en

```
class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
```

> Class 'PlayerTask' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...)' in 'AsyncTask

.Desde ya muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer y darme una mano .

Comment: ¿Por que tienes dos doInBackground? =S   Te va a ejecutar el que tiene @Override, vamos, el que tienes a null...

Comment: Tienes razón !, descuido mio ,aunque este doInBackground y @overide lo coloqué con el solucionador de errores del compilado ,ahora que lo quite tengo  una linea con error .Lo edito así solucionamos el problema real .Gracias

Comment: Buenas @EliseoBaroni realice la ejecución de tu código y el error que emite es debido a que el método `protected Boolean doinBackground(String...String)` lo tienes escrito con minuscula en la 'i' de `doinBackground`, esto lo cambien por `doInBackground` que es como solicita la implementan del metodo `protected Boolean doInBackground(String...String)`, y me logro reproducir sin problemas el enlace. esto solo lo comento en caso de que aun no hayas podido resolver tu consulta.